# What is the purpose of '/' in awk command?

Tags: awk

Why does this works :

```
echo 'NetRange:192.168.1.1-192.168.255.255' | awk -F: '/NetRange/ {print $2}'
```

and this doesn't

```
echo 'NetRange:192.168.1.1-192.168.255.255' | awk -F: 'NetRange {print $2}'
```

What is the purpose of `/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to grep and find command -

Say for example -  if you want to search for a word "hello" on a txt file "Firstprog.txt".

```
awk '/hello/' Firstprog.txt
```

This tells Awk to search through the file for lines of text that contain the string "hello", and print them out.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer , another thing , so this will print line no matter where 'hello' is located inside line?

Comment: Yes, anywhere in the line. The stuff between the `/.../` is a *regular expression*, so you can create very complex matches.